# Getting MySQL result with descending order applied on specific columns

Tags: mysql

I have a table in MySQL with column names as follows,

```
---------------------------------------------------------
Sno | Name  | Status    | Build_01 | Build_02 | Build_03 
---------------------------------------------------------
```

Here, the table will grow in column-wise as well as we are updating the status for each build.

Now, when I use the select commands as

```
SELECT * FROM mytable where Name='dinesh'
```

I can get the result as per the table order like `Build_01,Build_02,Build_03` sequentially. But, I want to get them as `Build_03,Build_02,Build_01` ? i.e. sorting the specific column names in descending order while fetching the results

We can choose the column names as

```
select Sno,Name,Status,Build_03,Build_02,Build_01 where Name='dinesh'
```

Here, I have to provide all the column names one by one which I dont want. Because I have lot of columns for builds.

How can I achieve this ?

Note : I dont want to rearrange the column names, as the production code appending column names to the existing table.

Comment: your question is not clear  .. add a proper data sample and the expetced  result

Comment: You could reorder the column positions in your MySQL table, and then use `SELECT *`.  But `SELECT *` is generally a bad thing to do.  What is your aversion to listing out the columns?  This is probably the only way to do what you want, short of using dynamic SQL (which would be ugly).

Comment: Consider revising your schema design. Any time you find yourself with enumerated columns alarm bells should start ringing.

Comment: `ORDER BY <column> DESCENDING` https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-sorting-results.htm

Answer (score 0):

SQL is designed to order rows not columns but you can do this by building a sql statement using the ordinal position in information_schema.columns and executing it (dynamic sql) for example

```
drop table if exists t;

create table t(id int, b1 int,b2 int,b3 int);
insert into t values (1,1,2,3);
set @sql = (
concat
(
'select id,',
(
select group_concat(column_name order by ordinal_position desc)
from information_schema.columns
where table_name = 't' and table_schema = 'sandbox'  and ordinal_position > 1
)
,' from t'
)
);

prepare sqlstmt from @sql;
execute sqlstmt;
deallocate prepare sqlstmt;

+------+------+------+------+
| id   | b3   | b2   | b1   |
+------+------+------+------+
|    1 |    3 |    2 |    1 |
+------+------+------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```